# Restrict access to a specific user who is member of a group that has access to the SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have given a browser level of access to a group. Now I want to hide the report from a person who is a part of that group but the other members of that group should still be able to view the report. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't believe you can deny one user from a group in SSRS. It's not that granular. You need to create a new AD group and exclude the user.